# Access rules from java Weka PART rules

Tags: java, weka, j48

I'm trying to access rules generated from PART rules algorithm. 
I understand PART in turn converts nodes from J48 decision tree. I need to access each rule separately and display the same.

```
PART part1=new PART();
Instances instance1= new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.arff")));
d1.setClassIndex(instance1.numAttributes()-1);
part1.setUnpruned(false);
part1.setNumFolds(5);
part1.setMinNumObj(2);
part1.setReducedErrorPruning(true);
part1.setConfidenceFactor(0.25f);
part1.setBinarySplits(true);
part1.buildClassifier(instance1);
```

part1 is having an attribute m_root which is private. I'm unable to access this
Please suggest or guide me in the right direction

Thank you all